# How to get the Image "title" attribute value into another element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to display the title value of the image (class name: media_image) in another p tag (class name: media_folder_title) for every row. But I can't able to get the value. I have attached the sample code here.

Screenshot:

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div id="media-folder">
   <div class="media_folder">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
      <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5382" title="Test" class="media_image">
      <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="media_folder">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
      <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5383" title="test1" class="media_image">
      <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="media_folder">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
      <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5118" title="Uploads" class="media_image">
      <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(".media_folder img.media_image").each(function(){
    var imgtitle = $(this).attr("title");
    console.log(imgtitle);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("settimout ok");
        $(this).append("<p>"+imgtitle+"</p>");
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `$(this)` in the timeout because it's no longer the image but the window.

Also, `append` aims to append an element inside another element. It's not possible appending an element inside an image.
As your snippet implies, you want to append the `p` tag **after** the image, [`after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) is the right function for that.

```js
$(".media_folder img.media_image").each(function() {
  const $img = $(this);
  const imgtitle = $img.attr("title");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $img.after("<p>" + imgtitle + "</p>");
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<div id="media-folder">
  <div class="media_folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
    <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5382" title="Test" class="media_image">
    <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="media_folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
    <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5383" title="test1" class="media_image">
    <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="media_folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
    <img src="/img/artist/default.jpg" alt="5118" title="Uploads" class="media_image">
    <p class="media_folder_title"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, It's working. :)

Comment: Good call, trying to access title returns the document title in that case. 

OP, is a timeout required or would it be sufficient to use fadeIn() or show() if the element should become visible later?

Comment: @VetrivelPandiyarajan glad to hear :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Change the selectors in the first line into:

```
.media_folder img .media_image
```

Sometimes **space** is important.

Comment: This won't change anything, as OP wants to select the image with the class .media_image and not an element in <img> tag

Comment: .media_image is class name of the <img /> tag. So if we use the space, then .media_image class name is consider as child element of the <img /> tag.

Comment: no - That would just ensure that it will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to append something inside an `img` tag, which is not possible - as with a few other html elements.

What you are looking for is `$.after()`

Try `$(this).after($('<p />').text(imgtitle))`